# Using arrays in cobol to loop through clients and booking type

Tags: arrays, cobol

**Trying to solve this using arrays.**

Here's the problem: [image]

*Problem I'm facing:* Has to be an easier way to loop through the booking types. When I view the output, it shows the customer number, customer name, and address several times with the same input which it shouldn't be.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the program below:**

```
 Process Apost.
 Identification Division.
 Program-ID. BOOKINGARR.

*
* Page 554 No 3. ARRAYS.
* Data in sequence by Client No. Print the average cost of 
* trip for each booking type. Use arrays.
* 
 Environment Division.
 Configuration Section.
 Source-Computer.  IBM-AS400.
 Object-Computer.  IBM-AS400.
 Input-Output Section.
 File-Control.
     Select Input-File Assign to Database-Bookingpf.
     Select Output-File Assign to Printer-Qsysprt.
 Data Division.
 File Section.

  FD Input-File.
  01 Input-File-Rec.
      Copy DDS-BookingR of Bookingpf.

  FD Output-File.
   01 Output-File-Rec         Pic x(120).
  Working-Storage Section.

    01 END-OF-FILE          PIC X           VALUE 'N'.

    01 WS-ARRAY.
       05 WS-TABLE-ENTRIES OCCURS 4 TIMES.
          10 WS-TOTAL-COST                 PIC 9(7)V99.
          10 WS-TRIP-COUNT                 PIC 999.
          10 WS-AVG-COST                   PIC 9(7)V99 VALUE ZERO.
          10 WS-BOOKING-TYPE               PIC 9.

     01 ARRAY-INDEX                         PIC 99.
     01 EMPTY-POINTER                       PIC 99.
     01 ARRAY-EMPTY                         PIC XXX.


      01 PROGRAM-HEADER.
         05                        PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
         05                        PIC X(10) VALUE 'CLIENT NO.'.
         05                        PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
         05                        PIC X(11) VALUE 'CLIENT NAME'.
         05                        PIC X(6)  VALUE SPACES.
         05                        PIC X(14) VALUE 'CLIENT ADDRESS'.
         05                        PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
         05                        PIC X(9)  VALUE 'BOOK TYPE'.
         05                        PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
         05                        PIC X(12) VALUE 'AVERAGE COST'.
      01 REPORT-LINE.
         05                        PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
         05  CLIENTNO-OUT          PIC 999.
         05                        PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
         05  CLIENTNA-OUT          PIC X(16).
         05                        PIC X(1)  VALUE SPACES.
         05  CLIENTADD-OUT         PIC X(19).
         05                        PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.
         05  BOOKTYPE-OUT          PIC Z.
         05                        PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
         05  AVGCOST-OUT           PIC $Z,ZZ9.99.
         05                        PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.

    Procedure Division. 
    000-MAIN.
      OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE 
          OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.
      PERFORM 100-MOVE.
      PERFORM 1000-READ.
      PERFORM 300-UPDATE-BOOKINGS
              UNTIL END-OF-FILE = 'Y'.
      WRITE OUTPUT-FILE-REC FROM PROGRAM-HEADER.
      PERFORM 600-WRITE-TO-SCREEN
              VARYING ARRAY-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
              UNTIL ARRAY-INDEX > 4.
      CLOSE INPUT-FILE, OUTPUT-FILE.
      STOP RUN.

    100-MOVE.
       MOVE 1      TO EMPTY-POINTER.
       MOVE 'Y'    TO ARRAY-EMPTY.
       MOVE SPACES TO UPDATE-DONE.
       PERFORM 150-ZERO-OUT-ARRAY
               VARYING ARRAY-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
               ARRAY-INDEX > 4.

    150-ZERO-OUT-ARRAY.
       MOVE ZEROS TO  WS-BOOKING-TYPE    (ARRAY-INDEX).
       MOVE ZEROS TO  WS-TOTAL-COST      (ARRAY-INDEX).
       MOVE ZEROS TO  WS-TRIP-COUNT      (ARRAY-INDEX).
       MOVE ZEROS TO  WS-AVG-COST        (ARRAY-INDEX).

    1000-READ.
       READ INPUT-FILE AT END MOVE 'Y' TO END-OF-FILE.


    300-UPDATE-BOOKINGS.
     IF ARRAY-EMPTY = 'Y'
        PERFORM 400-ADD-1-TO-COUNT
        MOVE 'N' TO ARRAY-EMPTY
     ELSE
        MOVE 'N' TO UPDATE-DONE
        PERFORM 500-GET-BOOKING-AVERAGE
           VARYING ARRAY-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL ARRAY-INDEX = EMPTY-POINTER
                      OR
           UPDATE-DONE = 'Y'.

     IF UPDATE-DONE = 'N'
        PERFORM 400-ADD-1-TO-COUNT.

     PERFORM 1000-READ.

   400-ADD-1-TO-COUNT.
     MOVE BOOKTYPE   TO WS-BOOKING-TYPE (EMPTY-POINTER).
     ADD 1           TO WS-TRIP-COUNT   (EMPTY-POINTER).
     MOVE COSTOFTRIP TO WS-TOTAL-COST   (EMPTY-POINTER).
     MOVE COSTOFTRIP TO WS-AVG-COST     (EMPTY-POINTER).
     ADD 1 TO EMPTY-POINTER.

   500-GET-BOOKING-AVERAGE.
    IF BOOKTYPE = WS-BOOKING-TYPE      (ARRAY-INDEX)
       ADD 1 TO WS-TRIP-COUNT          (ARRAY-INDEX)
       ADD COSTOFTRIP TO WS-TOTAL-COST (ARRAY-INDEX)
       COMPUTE WS-AVG-COST (ARRAY-INDEX) =
            WS-TOTAL-COST (ARRAY-INDEX) / 
            WS-TRIP-COUNT (ARRAY-INDEX) 
       MOVE 'Y' TO UPDATE-DONE.

   600-WRITE-TO-SCREEN.
      MOVE CLIENTNO TO CLIENTNO-OUT.
      MOVE CLIENTNA TO CLIENTNA-OUT.
      MOVE CLIENTADD TO CLIENTADD-OUT.
      MOVE WS-BOOKING-TYPE (ARRAY-INDEX) TO BOOKTYPE-OUT.
      MOVE WS-AVG-COST (ARRAY-INDEX) TO AVGCOST-OUT.
      WRITE OUTPUT-FILE-REC FROM REPORT-LINE 
            AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
```

Comment: It would have been much better if you have edited your previous question on *exactly the same issue*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845134/cobol-programmers-how-to-use-arrays

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Stern & Stern.

The objective:

> Print the average cost of a trip for each booking type. Use arrays.

means the output should contain only two columns and four rows, plus any header. For example,

```
Booking Type      Average Cost
------------      ------------
Cruise                ZZZZ9.99
Air-Independent       ZZZZ9.99
Air-Tour              ZZZZ9.99
Other                 ZZZZ9.99
```

To achieve that you will need to place the four descriptions in an array and accumulate the total cost and count, for each booking type, also in an array. After processing all the records, calculate the averages and print the results while looping through the array(s).

You tried to do much more than was requested!

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind numbering COBOL paragraphs is so they are easier to find.  In a program several thousand lines long it saves significant effort for the maintainer.  You have located paragraph 1000 between paragraphs 150 and 300.

Modern COBOL programs usually have full stops at the end of a paragraph or section name and the end of a  paragraph or section.  Some people make the last line of a paragraph or section a `CONTINUE` or `EXIT` statement with a full stop instead of just a full stop on its own.

Modern COBOL programs use explicit scope terminators, particularly on `IF` statements, instead of full stops.

COBOL is criticized for being verbose; many COBOL programmers make this into a virtue by naming their paragraphs to indicate what is being done by the code contained therein.  For example, `100-MOVE` might be better named `100-INITIALIZE`.

On Stack Overflow, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the "code sample" button, the "{}" rather than marking your paragraphs in bold.

If the point of the exercise is to compute the average cost of each type of booking, I suggest using the booking type as a subscript into an array.  For each record you read, add the `COSTOFTRIP` to `WS-TOTAL-COST(BOOKTYPE)` and increment `WS-TRIP-COUNT(BOOKTYPE)`.  At end of file compute the average cost of a trip for each `BOOKTYPE` by using a `COMPUTE` for each element of the array inside a `PERFORM VARYING` loop.

For extra credit, verify `BOOKTYPE` is numeric before using it as a subscript and use an in-line `PERFORM` to compute the average.

Comment: Is there anyway you could step me through the Procedure Division? I am so confused with it. cschneid

Comment: @GreenSaucer42 this isn't really the right place to ask someone to tell you what the program is doing.